# SQL Server: get and sum lowest values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't figure out the SQL statement for getting the lowest `on_hand` by store and SKU and then sums it up.

Here's my sample table. Note `sku` and `store` is a `composite key`.

[image]

The result I'm looking for is `16`: `(10 + 5 + 1)`

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show us your attempts as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do this with  a subquery. This gets your answer of 16 that you are looking for:

```
    SELECT   SUM (min_by_store)
    FROM     (SELECT     Store, min(on_hand) AS min_by_store
                FROM     #Temp AS T
            GROUP BY     Store) AS MBS
```

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select sum(on_hand)
from t
where t.sku = (select top (1) t2.sku
               from t t2
               where t2.store = t.store
               order by t2.on_hand
              );
```